# registered user area package

Tags: php

I want to create a new service which needs a registered user area. I need to customize the fields and look of this rua. I am writing cause I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Is there an opensource php script I can use in a project that simply handles the security issues which I can access with something like:

```
if ($registered)
{
// things
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UserCake (usercake.com) might be something you're looking for.

Comment: Not that old, and it does what you want.  [Zend ACL](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.introduction.html) would also be a very good choice.

Answer (score 0):

The registered list will usually come in the form of SQL entries.